# phpMyAdmin é seguro contra bruteforce?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Bom, a minha pergunta, é a seguinte:

O phpMyAdmin tem alguma segurança contra bruteforce na password? Ou seja, ao final de x tentativas, o IP fica bloqueado ou alguma coisa parecida?

Obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo limitar o PHPmyadmin ao acesso de alguns IPs + url secreta, e isso nem garante muita coisa, fora que phpmyadmin é uma péssima ferramenta (ao meu ver), além de bem pesada. Existem ferramentas melhores e Desktop.

Comment: Em outras palavras, a solução mais simples é tirar o phpmyadmin, aí já resolve vários problemas de uma vez só ;)

Comment: Pois, estive a pensar e se calhar o melhor mesmo, é ter acesso ao bd através de Navicat, ou algum programa desses. É um risco que estou a correr desnecessariamente.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do phpMyAdmin [aqui](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-protect-phpmyadmin-against-brute-force-attacks), é recomendado a utilização de logs para o controle de tentativas de acesso já que não existe nada oficial para "contornar" um ataque de força bruta. Isso significa que é necessário utilizar o apache com configurações de manuseio de acesso.

Caso venha utilizar o phpmyadmin em endereço público recomendo nomenclaturas de diretórios "incomuns", evitando por exemplo: `site/phpmyadmin` ou `site/pma` o que já diminui um pouco a enumeração contra o sistema.

Comment: Concordo com o Turq. Se puder, o melhor mesmo é não deixar o phpMyAdmin público. Devs e administradores devem acessar a rede interna com uma VNP ou algo do gênero. Sobre o controle via logs eu recomendaria o [Fail2Ban](http://serverfault.com/questions/435016/custom-fail2ban-filter-for-phpmyadmin-bruteforce-attempts)

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, eu não recomendaria deixar o PHPMyAdmin exposto na Web. É uma ferramenta com muitas vulnerabilidades e não só brute force, o que pode colocar em risco as suas aplicações. Eu procurei as vulnerabilidades que a ferramenta possuí no site CVE Details, e foram encontradas 223 vulnerabilidades disponíveis. Existem modos de liberar o PHPMyAdmin apenas para o seu IP, ou então deixá-lo no servidor em modo inativo, e você pode ligá-lo apenas quando for utilizá-lo. Espero ter ajudado!

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-784/product_id-1341/Phpmyadmin-Phpmyadmin.html

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é utilizar o `fail2ban` para bloquear determinados padrões de acesso.

Tendo o fail2ban instalado, a configuração é mais ou menos assim, pode variar dependendo do seu servidor:

> /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{userID}n %{userStatus}n" pma_combined
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log pma_combined
```

Filtro do fail2ban:

> /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
[Definition]
denied = mysql-denied|allow-denied|root-denied|empty-denied
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*(?:%(denied)s)$
ignoreregex =
```

Adicionar uma jail:

> /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[phpmyadmin]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = phpmyadmin
logpath = /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log
```

E pro fim reiniciar o apache eo fail2ban:

```
service  apache2 reload
service fail2ban reload
```

Fonte:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/142035